# Diamond Shape Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I want to make a diamond shape as a background like this

[image]

1- i tried to rotate the view 45 degree but it becomes as an haxagon (why? i did not understand)

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(iv21,"rotation",0,45);
        animator.start();
```

2- i tried DiamondImageView from a library but it shows view as a diamond but its original position remains same when i click on it.

```
 <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.DiamondImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:siBorderType="fill"
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        app:siBorderWidth="2dp"
        app:siBorderColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        />
```

so if it is possible to make layout using drawable xml it will be very good.